# Removing Gmail Recovery Options as G Suite Super Admin

Tags: gmail, account-recovery, google-workspace-for-business

I am a Super Admin for my company's G Suite. I need to access the inbox of a former employee. Despite resetting the password, an attempt to log in says that my computer is not recognized and it prompts me to use one of the recovery options to gain access via a cell phone number on file.

How do I remove the recovery options so I can access the e-mail inbox?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to disable two-step identification is G Suite temporarily.  Log in at admin.google.com with the administrator account.  Search for the User or find it under the Users list.  Inside the User account, click Security, and you have the option to turn off 2 Step Identification.

Then you should be able to log in.

As of Feb 2019, I'm referencing the steps below.  They've changed repeatedly over the last few years so who knows what the steps will be next year.   https://support.google.com/a/answer/2537800?hl=en

Note that this works for company-controlled accounts.  I've never tried to recover the password of the actual account admin, which is probably more complex or limited for good reasons.